# Counting the number of labelled unicyclic graphs via Lagrange inversion

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees

I am struggling with the following exercise:

> Let $\mathcal{U}$ be the class of labelled unicyclic graphs, i.e. connected graphs with precisely one cylce. Express $\mathcal{U}$ in terms of basic constructions involving the class of $\mathcal{T}$ of Cayley trees and find a sum formula for the number $u_n$ of labelled unicyclic graphs on $n$ vertices using the Lagrange inversion theorem.

I understand that $\mathcal{U}$ can be seen as an undirected cylce of size $\ge 3$ (due to the implicit assumption of the graph being simple, so no loops or double edges), where the "nodes" are Cayley trees. Thus

$$ \mathcal{U} = UCYC_{\ge 3}(T),$$

which implies the EGF

$$U(z) = \frac{1}{2} \log \bigg( \frac{1}{1-T(z)} \biggr) - \frac{T(z)}{2} - \frac{T(z)^2}{4}.$$

However, I do not see where to use the Lagrange inversion formula here, as nowhere appears something of the form $y(z) = z \phi (y(z))$.

Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer using Egorychev method by way of enrichment.
Note that the group acting on the cycle is the dihedral group $D_q$
and not just the cyclic group $C_q.$ We assume that two graphs where we
get the second by turning over the first are considered the same.
We thus have the combinatorial class equation

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{U} = \textsc{DHD}_{\ge 3}(\mathcal{T}).$$

This gives the EGF

$$U(z) = \sum_{q\ge 3} \frac{T(z)^q}{2q}
= \frac{1}{2} \log\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
- \frac{T(z)}{2} - \frac{T(z)^2}{4}.$$

The quantity we seek is $$n! [z^n] U(z) = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] U'(z).$$
This is given by

$$(n-1)! \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^n} U'(z)
= (n-1)! \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^n}
\left[\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-T(z)}
- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} T(z) \right] T'(z).$$

Now put $T(z) = w.$ We have from the combinatorial class specification
that

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{T})$$

so that

$$T(z) = z \exp T(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad z = T(z) \exp(-T(z)).$$

We thus obtain

$$(n-1)! \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{\exp(nw)}{w^n}
\left[\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-w}
- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} w \right]
\\ = (n-1)! [w^{n-1}] \exp(nw)
\left[\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-w}
- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} w \right].$$

Extract the coefficient to obtain

$$\frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \times
\left[ \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^q}{q!}
- \frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} - \frac{n^{n-2}}{(n-2)!} \right].$$

We thus have the sum formula

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{2} (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-3} \frac{n^q}{q!}.}$$

This gives the sequence [OEIS A057500](https://oeis.org/A057500)

$$0, 0, 1, 15, 222, 3660, 68295, 1436568, 33779340,
880107840, \ldots$$

where  we  see  we  have  the right  data.  The  traditional  Lagrange
inversion  probably refers  to  the functional  equation  of the  tree
function $T(z).$

Note that the OEIS says we  are counting connected labeled graphs with
$n$   edges   and   $n$   nodes.   This   is   the   same   statistic,
however. Supposing such a graph had  more than one cycle then there is
a cycle from  which we may remove  one edge to obtain a  graph with at
least one other  cycle remaining. The graph is still  connected as the
rest of the cycle can replace the removed edge. But if it is connected
and has $n-1$ edges  it must be a tree, a  contradiction as there were
cycles left over  that we didn't touch by removing  the edge. So these
graphs contain  at most  one cycle.  And this  is indeed  what happens
since otherwise  we would have  a tree,  again a contradiction  by the
number of nodes.